# Python function and output issue

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to write a script which I want to compile into an exe that we can use at work for collecting some diagnostic info for a particular application. The application has log files in the program directory, and I'm writing the script to get the program folder from the registry.

Now if I do this, it does actually output the path

```
    OMExists = True
    try:
            hKey = _winreg.OpenKey (_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r"SOFTWARE\Level Platforms\Managed Workplace\Onsite Manager\Install")
            value, type = _winreg.QueryValueEx (hKey, "PATH")
    except WindowsError:
            Print
    print (value)
```

But if I write it like this, I get nothing...this is where I'm looking for a quick hand. I'm sure this is simple, but I'm just not seeing it at the moment because from what I can tell it should work.

```
def Check_OM():
        OMExists = True
        try:
                hKey = _winreg.OpenKey (_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r"SOFTWARE\Level Platforms\Managed Workplace\Onsite Manager\Install")
                value, type = _winreg.QueryValueEx (hKey, "PATH")
        except WindowsError:
                Print
        print (value)

Check_OM
```

Comment: If you're just starting out with Python, using exactly four spaces for indentation is a good habit to get into. Not eight, and no tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't *calling*  the function (just referencing it, which is legal Python but doesn't do anything):

```
Check_OM()  # forgot the parentheses :)
```

Comment: Doh, Had a feeling it was something simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To call the function, do

```
Check_OM()
```

Note the parentheses `()` at the end

If you're interested, you can read a little bit more about functions [here in the python docs](https://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/functions.html)